# Xcode 12.2 unable to run on device after stripping architecture

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, arm, xcode12

My iOS apps were running fine until I installed Xcode 12.2 on macOS Big Sur. With Xcode 12 we have arm64 and one of the frameworks required excluding it.

So, I set that from the App Build Settings tab, under Excluded Architectures, by adding a row for Release and Debug builds with the key-value Any iOS Simulator SDK and arm64.

The app runs fine on the simulator. But as soon as I run it on a device/archive it, it throws an error:

> Lipo was unable to detect any architectures.

PS: Though, when I remove the following build rules to strip archs for a specific framework, it works... but I need to keep this script to ensure the app size remains small.

```
APP_PATH="${TARGET_BUILD_DIR}/${WRAPPER_NAME}"

# remove unused architectures from embedded frameworks
find "$APP_PATH" -name '*.framework' -type d | while read -r FRAMEWORK
do
    FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_NAME=$(defaults read "$FRAMEWORK/Info.plist" CFBundleExecutable)
    FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH="$FRAMEWORK/$FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_NAME"
    echo "Executable is $FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH"

    EXTRACTED_ARCHS=()

    if [[ $FRAMEWORK == *"Specific Framework"* ]]; then        

    for ARCH in $ARCHS
    do
        echo "Extracting $ARCH from $FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_NAME"
        lipo -extract "$ARCH" "$FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH" -o "$FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH-$ARCH"
        EXTRACTED_ARCHS+=("$FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH-$ARCH")
    done

    echo "Merging extracted architectures: ${ARCHS}"
    lipo -o "$FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH-merged" -create "${EXTRACTED_ARCHS[@]}"
    rm "${EXTRACTED_ARCHS[@]}"

    echo "Replacing original executable with thinned version"
    rm "$FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH"
    mv "$FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH-merged" "$FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH"
    
    fi
   

done
```